# Search and replace multiple special characters with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

Currently this will take the text from the textarea and replace all the characters that are specified in the charMap:

```
<form>
<textarea name="text" id="text" style="width:300px; height:200px;"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

var charMap = {
    "Å":'x',
    "å":'y',
    "b":'z',
    "c":'f'
};

$('#submit').click(function() {

    var str = $('#text').val();
    var str_array = str.split('');

    for( var i = 0, len = str_array.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        str_array[ i ] = charMap[ str_array[ i ] ] || str_array[ i ];
    }

    foo = str_array.join('');
    $('#text').val(foo);

});
```

The problem is that it does not recognise the special characters. So it will replace 'b' and 'c' but not 'Å' and 'å'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean these specific replacements, or swapping the letter with the letter that is `n` characters from the end of the alphabet (where `n` is the current letters position in the alphabet)?

Comment: @Hamish - I'd like those specific replacements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I'm understanding the requirements better, you can just create a map of characters to replacements like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gaG28/2/

```
var charMap = {
    a:'z',b:'v',c:'n',d:'s',e:'d',
    f:'k',g:'e',h:'y',i:'j',j:'r',
    k:'f',l:'m',m:'a',n:'c',o:'q',
    p:'t',q:'g',r:'i',s:'b',t:'p',
    u:'l',v:'u',w:'h',x:'o',y:'w',z:'x'
};
var str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

var str_array = str.split('');

for( var i = 0, len = str_array.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    str_array[ i ] = charMap[ str_array[ i ] ] || str_array[ i ];
}
str = str_array.join('');
```

This will also leave any characters alone that are not found in the map.

Comment: Thats great. The only problem I'm having is that I want to replace some special characters such as 'å' with '&aring;'. When I try using these character is returns a nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot patrick but your revision didn't work for me, please see my edit in the original question.

Comment: @Dave - It seems to work for me. [Here's an updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/gaG28/3/) with the characters you referenced in you question. If `Å:'&Aring;'` doesn't work for you, try placing the key in quotes, like `"Å":'&Aring;'`. When placing the key in quotes, pretty much any character should be accepted as they key name.

Comment: Nice one, the double quotes sorted it

Comment: @patrick dw - ACtually that's no better. It works perfectly in jsfiddle but it will not work in an actual HTML file. It will pickup the normal characters but not the special characters even if I wrap them in double quotes?

Comment: @Dave - I'd have to see how you're actually using it. In the example, it is done completely in javascript. If you have `&Aring;` in your HTML file, it will give you `Å` when you retrieve the innerHTML (or whatever). The quotes I added (single or double, doesn't matter) were just to add support if there are browsers that don't allow such characters as key names in javascript. I see you updated your question. I'll take another look.

Comment: @Dave - [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/gaG28/6/) using the new code in your question. Seems to work fine. The JSFiddle is an actual HTML doc, so it shouldn't be any different. Is there a particular browser giving you issues?

Comment: @patrick dw - I had it working perfectly in jsfiddle too. But in my html document it replaces all characters accept special characters. I have tested in chrome and ff and same result. Could it be my charset or lang attributes, I'm using html5 'utf-8' and 'en'

Comment: @Dave - Yes, I see. I get the same thing. Not sure what the cause is.

Comment: @patrick dw -  Thanks for the help patrick, answer accepted. I'll figure the special character issue out myself

Answer (score 2):

Since [`.replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) acts on a string, and returns a string, you can chain multiple replace calls together:

```
var text = $(this).val().replace(/a/g, "z").replace(/b/g, "y").replace(/c/g, "x");
```

Comment: I also thought of doing it this way but I would like to do it using just one regular expression

Comment: @DaveKingsnorth hmm...ok. I'm trying to think if that's even possible using JS regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is correct, however the problem is due to the charset of the page, try the following:

1. Make sure your page is saved as UTF-8
2. Include the following in your header

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I was head scratching with the same problem, this resolved my issue.